# Source path of PackageInstaller

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have this (working) code, where `pkgName` is "myNugetPackage"

```
var componentModel = (IComponentModel)GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
IVsPackageInstallerServices installerServices = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstallerServices>();
if (!installerServices.IsPackageInstalled(project, pkgName))
{
    IVsPackageInstaller installer = (IVsPackageInstaller)componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstaller>();
    installer.InstallPackage("All", project, pkgName, (System.Version)null, false);
}
```

Unfortunately I have to modify the nuget package "myNugetPackage" but I don't know where I can find it on my computer.

What's the path where the PackageInstaller looks up the nuget packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the package installer created a connection to the official nuget server and loaded the package from there.
In order to change the package I had to define my own package source (Tools -> Options -> Package Manager -> Package Sources) and give it a higher priority than the official server (by clicking on the "up"-arrow). Now I'm able to save the changed package at the defined location and the package manager will use it instead of the official one.